# how to right align h:outputlink in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using JSF 1.1 and I have added two `<h:outputtext />` and one  `<h:outputlink />` in a `<rich:column />`.

Now while displaying the data in `<rich:column />`, I want the icon containing the  `<h:outputlink/>` to be aligned right in the rich column. As now I am getting all the three components value one below the other. Can any body suggest me a good solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<rich:column styleClass="rightalign">
    <!-- column content here -->
</rich:column>
```

And add in your .css file

```
td.rightalign {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use css styling.  In most browsers, you can hit f12 (ie or firefox w/firebug plugin) and then play with various css values to see which one works best for you.  Then add those CSS values into your code so that it renders that way from the start.  Good luck!